# I can't pass data to other component

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am using Next.js typescript and material ui. I created MyOrders component. I want pass data MyOrders to MyorderItem. I can't pass data to MyOrderItem.

Below my code doesn't working. I got an error. Where should change my code?

```
import { MyOrderItemsData } from '@/types/MyOrderItemsData';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import MyOrderItem from './MyOrderItem';

const orders: MyOrderItemsData[] = [
  {
    orderId: '81318551 - 0003',
    productName: 'React Exports Performance Headset',
    productThumbnail: '../src/assets/images/product-2.png',
    productDescription: 'Color Black RGB, 270gr',
    sallerName: 'nicolayritz1337',
    deliveryTime: 'February 14',
    price: '$199.99',
    quantity: 1,
  },
  {
    orderId: '81318551 - 0002',
    productName: 'React Esports Perforrmance Heaadset',
    productThumbnail: '../src/assets/images/product-2.png',
    productDescription: 'Colour Black RGB, 270gr',
    sallerName: 'nicolayritz1337',
    deliveryTime: 'February 14',
    price: '$109.00',
    quantity: 1,
  },
  {
    orderId: '81318551 - 0001',
    productName: 'Gaming Headset Krraken X USB',
    productThumbnail: '../src/assets/images/product-2.png',
    productDescription: 'Colour Black, 240gr',
    sallerName: 'nicolayritz1337',
    deliveryTime: 'February 14',
    price: '$79.00',
    quantity: 1,
  },
];
const MyOrders: React.FC = () => (
  <Box>
    {orders.map((order, index) => (
      <MyOrderItem
      key={order.orderId} 
      index={index} 
      order={order}
      />
    ))}
  </Box>
);
export default MyOrders;
```

This is MyOrderItem component

```
import { MyOrderItemsData } from '@/types/MyOrderItemsData';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { FC, useId } from 'react';

interface Props {
  product: MyOrderItemsData;
}


const MyOrderItem: FC<Props>= () => {
  
  return (
    <Box>
      <h1>OPI</h1>
    </Box>
    );
};

export default MyOrderItem;
```

I am many trying for passing data to  from MyOrder. But can't solve it. I don't understand where is my code in wrong.

Comment: Can you please mention the error you are getting?

Comment: {orders.map((order, index) => (
      <MyOrderItem
      key={order.orderId} 
      index={index} 
      order={order}
      />
    ))} see this code. My error is index = {index}

Comment: what I should do

Comment: Okay so first let me know the properties your `MyOrderItem` accepts.

Comment: Can you show `MyOrderItem` component?

Comment: yes, Where does this code show up?

Comment: Ok, I edited it. You can see.

Comment: I have answered below. Let's try it @MuhammadMehediHasan

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `interfaces/types` for `MyOrderItem`, that it have to the same `name of props` and `data type of each prop`, that you want to pass into `MyOrderItem` from `MyOrders`.

```
import { MyOrderItemsData } from '@/types/MyOrderItemsData';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { FC, useId } from 'react';

interface Props {
  order: MyOrderItemsData;
  index: string
}


const MyOrderItem: FC<Props>= ({order, index}) => {
  
  return (
    <Box>
      <h1>OPI</h1>
    </Box>
    );
};

export default MyOrderItem;
```

Comment: You're welcome. But if it works, press `Accept` and `Upvote` buttons.  That's `the real thank` @MuhammadMehediHasan